# Vmrun timeout command

Tags: linux, windows, bash, vmware

I wrote a script that use VMrun to run Vmware windows guest, run script inside that image and shutdown the VMware session. The script is as follow:

```
vmrun start XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx"  

~/Desktop$ vmrun -gu ** -gp ** runProgramInGuest XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx" "C:\Documents and Settings\Computer\Desktop\script.bat"

vmrun stop XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx"
```

However, the script go through the last two commands before the image is up and running, thus resulting not running the script inside the Windows guest. Is there any approach to wait till the image is up and then continue executing the commands?

Comment: Is there any command like: vmstatus? If you get status of vm state. You can check it with shell script.

Comment: Are you using VMware Workstation, VMware vSphere or another?

Comment: Yes, you can ping the machine and wait for the network to start

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions:

1.) Your machine will get a valid IP address and not the Windows `APIPA` address.

2.) You're running VMware Workstation (which has a `readVariable` option)

If this is the case you can ping the machine and wait for a valid IP and then execute your script this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

vmrun start XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx" 

win_ip=$(vmrun -T ws readVariable $YOUR_MACHINE guestVar ip)

# First loop waits for the address variable to populate
while [ -z $win_ip ]
do
   win_ip=$(vmrun -T ws readVariable $YOUR_MACHINE guestVar ip)
done

# Second loop waits for a valid address
while [ ! -z $(printf $win_ip | grep "169.254") ]
do
   win_ip=$(vmrun -T ws readVariable $YOUR_MACHINE guestVar ip)
done 

~/Desktop$ vmrun -gu ** -gp ** runProgramInGuest XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx" "C:\Documents and Settings\Computer\Desktop\script.bat"

vmrun stop XP/XP/"Windows XP Pro SP3_original.vmx"
```

Doing it this way ensures the network is fully initialized in case your script relies on the network for any functionality.